# compiled c program memory addresses

Tags: c, memory, gcc, assembly, gdb

I am trying to understand the following:

Given a small Hello World program in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
    }
}
```

When you compile this with gcc, and then examine the resulting .out file using objdump, you get something like the following:

```
08048374 <main>:
8048374:       55                      push   ebp
8048375:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
8048377:       83 ec 08                sub    esp,0x8
804837a:       83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
804837d:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
8048382:       29 c4                   sub    esp,eax
8048384:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x0
804838b:       83 7d fc 09             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0x9
804838f:       7e 02                   jle    8048393 <main+0x1f>
8048391:       eb 13                   jmp    80483a6 <main+0x32>
8048393:       c7 04 24 84 84 04 08    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048484
804839a:       e8 01 ff ff ff          call   80482a0 <printf@plt>
804839f:       8d 45 fc                lea    eax,[ebp-4]
80483a2:       ff 00                   inc    DWORD PTR [eax]
80483a4:       eb e5                   jmp    804838b <main+0x17>
80483a6:       c9                      leave  
80483a7:       c3                      ret    
80483a8:       90                      nop    
80483a9:       90                      nop    
80483aa:       90                      nop
```

The first column of values in the resulting .out file are memory addresses, if I understand correctly, these addresses contain the instructions that are following in the other columns.

Now my question: If you copy the file to a different machine (or a different location on the same machine even) and dump the file again these addresses should change to something else because the program will be at a different location in memory, correct? But if I do that, I get the exact same output, the same address values. Why is that? I clearly misunderstand the meaning of this first column, could somebody please explain to me what these addresses are exactly? Thanks in advance!

Update:
As I understand it now, thanks to Paul R's answer and some further wikipedia reading, these addresses are referencing a virtual address space in which the code is executed by the operating system of the machine on which it runs. These virtual addresses are mapped to absolute addresses on the actual machine by its operating system.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of memory and disk. The address is the address in _memory_ (also known as RAM, to keep it simple), while on _disk_ these addresses are not used. I suggest you learn more about the basic architecture of computers, like the difference between disk and memory.

Comment: "these addresses should change to something else because the program will be at a different location in memory, correct?" -- You're not dealing with a program in memory, you're dealing with an object file, that eventually will be loaded into memory.

Comment: I do understand the difference between memory and disk, my confusion came from not knowing that these addresses are virtual

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The addresses in the left column are the (virtual) addresses at which your code will be [loaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29) when it's run. Unless the code is [position-independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) it will need to be loaded at these addresses to run correctly.

Comment: I agree, but they are relative addresses, aren't they ?

Comment: @Razvan: not necessarily - it depends on whether the code is position-independent or not.

Comment: In general, in standard operating systems, shouldn't they be relative addresses ? Wouldn't it complicate things to make them absolute addresses as you have no guarantee that memory is available ?

Comment: @Razvan Do you know what a virtual address space is?

Comment: So in short, these addresses are addresses in a virtual address space which will be translated by the loader on the system on which the code is executed to absolute addresses, so the loader makes sure that the memory used by the code is not in use by any other processes?

Comment: Well the virtual memory subsystem is really a whole separate topic on its own, but yes, each process typically has its own virtual address space in a typical desktop or server OS, and you don't even need to think about physical addresses or the mapping between the two. The loader doesn't really play any part in this aspect of the system - it just loads the code into the required virtual address area.

Answer (score 2):

Every process in a 32-bit OS runs in its own 4GB virtual memory area. This area is shared between the kernel and your process, normally in as a 3GB/1GB memory split, where the lower 3GB memory area starting from 0x00000000 is used by the application while the upper 1GB is used by the kernel.

Now if we consider the lower 3GB user space area of the application, the area is further divided into different segments such as text segment, initialized data segment, uninitialized data segment etc.

So, the code that you write is placed in that text area which happens to be starting from 08048374 in your example.

Hence, the entire assembly code is placed in this virtual address, irrespective of any machine that you use to run it on, as this is pre-defined during the linking stage. Hence, this address will not change. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should either clarify that the sizes of 4 GB, 3 GB, etc that you mention in your answer are specific to typical 32 bit virtual memory operating systems only, or perhaps make the answer more generally applicable.

Comment: True. Edited the answer above to reflect 32-bit OS reference while describing the 4GB VM availablility per process. Thanks Paul.